# sql query to delete rows based on previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a sql query to delete rows that match the signature of the row after another row (grouped by a column [uix], ordered by date).
So for this data set:

```
uid u k date
-------
id1 a -
id2 g -
id1 a x
id1 b -
id1 b -
id2 g -
id1 b -
id1 a -
id2 f -
id1 a -
id1 a x
id2 g - 
id1 c - 
id2 h -
id1 c -
id1 c -
```

I want to delete all rows of (id1 b) and (id1 c) because they were the next row of id1 after row (id1 a x) when ordered by date.

The algorithm would be something like this:

for this row

delete all rows

where [row before this row k column] = x

and [all rows u column] = [this row u column]

grouped by uid

order by date

The resulting dataset would not contain any row of (id1 b) or (id1 c).

```
uid u k date
-------
id1 a -
id2 g -
id1 a x
id2 g -
id1 a -
id2 f -
id1 a -
id1 a x
id2 g - 
id2 h -
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is the desired output? Can you please add that?

Comment: Find the values you want using RowNumber, LEAD or LAG with a CTE and delete from the CTE.

Comment: When you say *next row* then there should be a column to order the rows

Comment: I changed the question per requests.

Comment: There is no "previous" or "next" row in sql. tables are unsorted by nature. you must specift how to order them as Prdp wrote.

Comment: LEAD and LAG were not implemented until SQL 2012. You can achieve the same result with some creative SQL using a CTE. 

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

Comment: A trivial complaint @ZoharPeled and one I'd already rectified before you commented. It's ordered by the date column. So next would be the next row when ordered by date.